# Creating table with sorted data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pivot-table

I have data from database (many records):

```
('group1', 272, 'Alex')
('group1', 268, 'Alex1')
('group2', 267, 'Kate')
('group2', 138, 'Stive')
('group2', 3081, 'Stive2')
...
('group3', 265, 'Dave')
```

I can write these data to the CSV file or to the list, but how to have the table with structure and with sorting by Name and by group_name via python 3.4:

```
Name  group1 group2 group3 ... groupN
Alex  True   False  False  ... 
Alex1 True   False  False  ...
...
```

maybe you can help me.

Comment: You should ideally sort and group  from the database before writing a file

Comment: would pandas be an option for you ?

Comment: I can sort data before writing a file.
"would pandas be an option for you ?"
> Yes

Comment: Then use pada to sort the data and save it. If you have problems, come back with your code after researching your errors via google and SO and then put up a new question, following [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First determine a list of required column names `cols` by creating a set of used names and then sorting them. With this you can then build a dictionary containing all the entries which are present:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

data = [('group1', 272, 'Alex'), ('group1', 268, 'Alex1'), ('group2', 267, 'Kate'), ('group2', 138, 'Stive'), ('group2', 3081, 'Stive2'),('group3', 265, 'Dave')]
cols = sorted(set(g for g, v1, v2 in data))
names = defaultdict(list)

for group, value, name in data:
    names[name].append(group)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Name'] + cols)

    for name in sorted(names.keys()):
        csv_output.writerow([name] + [col in names[name] for col in cols])
```

Giving you an output file:

```
Name,group1,group2,group3
Alex,True,False,False
Alex1,True,False,False
Dave,False,False,True
Kate,False,True,False
Stive,False,True,False
Stive2,False,True,False
```

Comment: Martin, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have read your data from the database into a list of tuples, you can try this:

```
import csv
data = [('group1', 272, 'Alex'), ('group1', 268, 'Alex1'), ('group2', 267, 'Kate'), ('group2', 138, 'Stive'), ('group2', 3081, 'Stive2'),('group3', 265, 'Dave')]
final_data = sorted([(c, *[a == i for i in ['group1', 'group2', 'group3']]) for a, b, c in data], key=lambda x:x[0])
print(final_data)
write = csv.writer(open('filename.csv'))
write.writerows([['Name', 'group1', 'group2', 'group3']]+final_data)
```

Output:

```
[('Alex', True, False, False), 
 ('Alex1', True, False, False), 
 ('Dave', False, False, True), 
 ('Kate', False, True, False), 
 ('Stive', False, True, False), 
 ('Stive2', False, True, False)]
```

Edit: for many possible groups:

```
groups = list(set(map(lambda x:x[0], data)))
final_data = sorted([(c, *[a == i for i in groups]) for a, b, c in data], key=lambda x:x[0])
write = csv.writer(open('filename.csv'))
write.writerows([['Name', *groups]]+final_data)
```

Comment: Thank you Ajax1234, 
but problem - I don't know these group_names (for adding it to the script before)

Comment: @Oleksii When you retrieve the data from the database, will there be a string in the first column that will match "group"+digit, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I have a list as you set (first column - this is group_name):
data = [('group1', 272, 'Alex'), ('group1', 268, 'Alex1'), ('group2', 267, 'Kate'), ('group2', 138, 'Stive'), ('group2', 3081, 'Stive2'),('group3', 265, 'Dave')]
but 1) I have more groups, 2) I have many names which present in different groups

Comment: data = [('group1', 521, 'Alex'), ('group1', 155, 'Alex1'), ('group1', 267, 'Kate'), ('group2', 138, 'Alex'), ('group2', 268, 'Dave'), ('group3', 1323, 'Alex'), ('group3', 171, 'Stive'), ('group4', 284, 'Alexі').......('groupN', 284, 'Name')]

Comment: @Oleksii thank you for the feedback. Please see my recent edit.